# Soundcloud Api - stream only specific part of the song starting at [ms]

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

Is there a method in Soundcloud JavaScript Api that would allow to stream only a specific part of the song starting from point A till the point B. I know it is possible with SoundManager 2 object to start playing a song with option e.g. {position:30000} from 30 sec and stop it using onposition event listener, but those methods operates on the WHOLE DOWNLOADED song. As stated in SoundManager documentation:

> object:SMSound setPosition can only seek within LOADED sound data, as defined by the duration property.

Now inspecting a https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html I found out that using Soundcloud Widget it is possible to send 206 Partial Content Get request that starts streaming at specified byte range without a need to download the whole file.

> **Range**  bytes=5537792-

So my final question is whether there is a possibility to send such request using Javascript SDK and optionally SoundManager.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will work.

Use the URL of the mp3 file and add the Range attribute, after that you will only get the defined bytes.

Url:

http://ec-media.soundcloud.com/73KFqGQlR0Oh.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7ef69b03d522cd6dfee9399eeb9a525089b6dfabf3dc40886820f53e6069f797c064d9d75630447ec4b26a04327f7ee9859fc779a0e2a3e211401=&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJNIGGLK7XA7YZSNQ&Expires=1397221105&Signature=9w9sc8feyYHme3qcCupJS%2FMc%2Be4%3D

Header-field / value:
Range / bytes=40000-41418

Screenshot:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26890303/http_range.PNG

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I ve checked it in all 3 browsers and it seems it s still downloading the whole file? Have you tested it and seen it downloading only a part? There is a possibility that I am doing sth wrong so it would be great to know that for sure.

Comment: In the browser it wont work, you are right, but you can use the url and define a range header for your request. Then it should work.